# Cakephp 2 Webtechnick Facebook Plugin - should we use it?

Tags: facebook, cakephp-2.0

As Facebook stops supporing FBML http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/ starting June 1, 2012 I'm wondering if I should use Webtechnick's Facebook Plugin as it uses quite a lot of FBML elements (for example the login and logout button).

Please let me know if I misunderstand this whole topic, but I'm currently thinking of just adding my own Facebook Connect Support (mainly for login in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seem the 2.0 branch is not supported by Nick Baker.
And the maintainera are not giving much attention to the plugin, (last commit as 3 month ago), and he does not give answer in the opened issues.
I read in somewhere (don't remeber where and don't know is it true) , that nick say it's not stable (2.0 branch).

But i'm using it (only a few features) and i had only one issue (https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/issues/51).

I'm using it and trying to fix issues and share it on github , you can do that too and help the plugin development. It seems a better idea that create a whole "Facebook Connect Support". The code is very simple and has very good documetation.

I have the same doubt, and i'm only showing you what made my call.

You can also enter in contact to:

Author: Nick Baker (nick@webtechnick.com)
CakePHP 2.0 support by Stefan Zhelyazkov (stz@seas.upenn.edu)